# MySQLi Table design

Tags: php, mysqli, database-design

I'm not particularly versed in database design and I've come into a problem.

The long and short of it is as follows: I'm putting a ladder up on a website for a sports league.

There will be multiple ladders that I would like to display on the same page but can't wrap my head around how to design the tables to do this.

I can easily create a table to house the data of matches for teams

i.e.:

```
TEAM | MATCHES WON | MATCHES LOST | POINTS
```

However I need the season, the division and the current round of the last update for each table. I'm sorry I feel like I'm explaining this badly.

A more visual representation of what I'm asking about might look like this:

---

```
Winter Season 2014

Premier Division

Round 12


TEAM | MATCHES WON | MATCHES LOST | POINTS

xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx

----------------------

Winter Season 2014

2nd Divison

Round 7


TEAM | MATCHES WON | MATCHES LOST | POINTS

xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx
```

---

I'm basically just confused as to the best way to link the tables so that the correct season displays the correct ladder

**EDIT:**

A bit more thinking and I've come up with an idea but I'm not sure if it will work. Is it possible to create a new table that has the name of a value of field. So the idea is, if I have a form that the site admin users to create a new season ladder. It pulls the Auto increment ID from the Season ladder table and adds 1 to this into a hidden field. E.g. if there are 4 already in the db it pulls 4, adds 1 to make it 5. This goes into a field called ladder as well as creates a table called 5 and thus can be easily linked?

Comment: To do this properly you should track date, teams playing and scores for each match. You'd also need to track which league each team is in for each season, and the dates of each season. Then you should be able to pull up  the usual `P W D L F A Diff Pts` format for any week of any league in any season. Setting this up will be a broader answer than appropriate for [so]

Answer (score 0):

Create a  Header type and Detail type take the possible redundant column in one table like for instance.

```
Table 1

Leauge_Name: Winter Season
League_Date: 2014
League_DivisionID: 1

Table 2

Division_ID: 1
Division_Set: 1st
Round_ID: 1

Table 3

Round_ID: 1
Round_Set: round 7
Team_One: Indiana
Team_Two: Miami
FirstT_Final: 107
SecondT_Final: 101
Match_Winner: Indiana
```

you can do that Connect the Table by each detail you want to take if you get my point..